# Cypress - Is it possible to verify text in prompt?

Tags: javascript, cypress, prompt

Is it possible to verify 'what's your sign'text in prompt?
Alert and Confirm can be verified text, but prompt I wonder if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a stub before the action that triggers the prompt:

Generally,

```js
let stub;

cy.window().then(win => {
  stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(' World')  // types this value 
})

cy.get('button-opening-prompt').click()

cy.wrap(stub).should(() => {
  expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith('Hello') // argument is the message
                                                // displayed in the prompt
})
```

A simple app that prompts after 2 seconds:

```html
<body>
  <div>Hello </div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const result = window.prompt('Hello')
      const div = document.querySelector('div')
      div.innerText += result 
    }, 2000)
  </script>
</body>
```

This can be tested with

```js
let stub;

cy.visit('http://127.0.0.1:5500/html/prompt.html', {   
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(' World')
  }
})

cy.get('div').should('contain', 'Hello World')   // checks the result added to page

cy.wrap(stub).should(() => {
  expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith('Hello')
})
```

#### Cancel button

To test the cancel button being pressed, substitute

```js
stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').callsFake(() => null)
```

Comment: Hi, how to test click 'Cancel' button after input into prompt textbox?

Comment: What would the expected result be? Does 'Cancel' even return any text entered?

Comment: 'Cancel' not return any text entered. I don't know how to implement code as step: 1. Open prompt; 2. Input value in textbox; 3. Click Cancel button

Comment: Yes true - that's what `.callsFake(() => null)` does. So then whatever is affected by the return value (in my example the `<div>Hello </div>`) will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign a variable name to the prompt code and retrieve its value by calling the variable.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
const num = Number(window.prompt("How old are you?", ""));

// now do some evaluation with conditional
let output = '';
                
// conditional stmt to see if input is higher or lower than US drinking age
num < 21 ? output = `Sorry but ${num} years old is not old enough to drink.` :
  output = `Excellent, at ${num} years old, you can drink.`;
  
// set mains text content to the output message we wish 
// to show depending on age user input into prompt
main.textContent = output;
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: I wanna verify text 'How old are you?' in prompt, not result after input.